# Magento2 - Remove tabs from admin edit forms

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin

For example remove "Related Products, Up-Sells, and Cross-Sells", "Configurations" or "Schedule Design Update" etc in product edit page:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to remove them?
You could ignore them when you create a new product.

In any case, I could hide them by javascript.

Comment: It is for user experience - they don't need the above at all. Not loading it will also increase page load.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I would like to do the same (for some sections of this page) but the previous comments were unhelpful at best?

Comment: @robgt After hours spent on code reviewing and questions asked on official forums with no answers I had to use CSS to hide them..

Comment: Er... Damn.....

Comment: Can you tell me how we can remove tabs according to product type.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/128668)

Answer (score 7):

You can hide these tabs ( configuration, design, search engine optimization) by using following code in `ui_component xml`.

> app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="configurable">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="design">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset name="search-engine-optimization">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

You can find fieldset name here,

[image]

Answer (score 1):

override this function

```
public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
{
}
```

and use this like a way

```
$meta = array_replace_recursive(
$meta,
[
    'content' => [
        'arguments' => [
            'data' => [
                'config' => [
                    'label' => __('')

                ],
            ],
        ],
        'children' => [],
    ],
]
);
```